# Sorting many labels in a tableView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom UITableviewCell which contains a few UILabels on them. The data is received from web services and I'd like to sort them based on one of the UILabels. The data received is stored in an array. How can I sort them?

Thanks! :)
Code written to add data to the cells from a BO:

```
cells.head.text = [[self.messageStore objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] subject];
            cells.subhead.text = [[self.messageStore objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] messageli];
            cells.signature.text=[AppConstants getUsername];
            cells.viewCount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Views",[[self.messageStore objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] viewsCount]];
            cells.interested.text= [[self.messageStore objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] interestedCount];
            cells.date.text = [[self.messageStore objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] creationDate];
            [cells.image1 sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[self.messageStore objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] imageURL]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_photo.png"]];
                cells.editZButton.hidden = NO;
            cells.editZButton.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
            cells.deleteZButton.hidden = NO;
            cells.amount.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %@",[[self.messageStore objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] priceAmount]];            cells.editZButton.tag = indexPath.section;
            cells.deleteZButton.tag = indexPath.section;
            [cells.editZButton addTarget:self action:@selector(editButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [cells.deleteZButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: do you want to sort to sort label text or sort an array? Sort the array first and then reload the table if content of array goes on the label.

Comment: label text. how do I do that?

Comment: Do you have array of dictionaries?

Comment: No. I don't. It's just a mutable array

Comment: so you have to show only specific labels? if possible please put some code so that your question can be more clear.

Comment: No. All the labels need to be show. I have edited the question with the code I use to show the label data from the array using the BO. The data stored in the array comes from a BO object from web services.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort the data using the predicate

```
NSPredicate *predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Your_Key ==%@",Your_Value_For_Key];
NSArray *array=[Your_Array_Of_Data filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't gave us the exact array to be sorted, I'm assuming its just a simple NSArray of strings.

You can use NSSortDescriptor to sort NSArray as below

```
NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Sam", @"John", @"Andrew", nil];
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"self" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortedArray = [arr sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Then reload your tableview with the "sortedArray".

Comment: self.messageStore containing a MessageBO with an NSString variable for creationDate is to be sorted. And shown from recently posted to older

Comment: give a sample array you are using

Comment: the data is received from webservices. the messageStore array holds BO objects and I will be accessing its properties from the array

Comment: like, messageStore has a BO, the BO holds NSString variables for price, creationDate and numberOfViews. I have to sort it such that the recently posted should be first, or high price to low price. The BO are accessed from the array like this: [[self.messageStore objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] creationDate]

Answer (score 0):

Below one is generic method, you can try.

```
- (NSMutableArray*)sortArray:(NSMutableArray*)dataArray filterKeyName:(NSString*)KeyName ascending:(BOOL)isAscending{

        NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:KeyName ascending:isAscending];
        [dataArray sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sorter]];

        return dataArray; // Sorted data array..
    }
```